# All lines of a file are printing over each other

Tags: ruby, file-io, printing, io

I am trying to print the contents of a file to the terminal.  When I run the script it prints all of the lines on top of each other, so I see the entire last line, the last bit of the other lines, etc.  I have tried executing from Powershell and cmd, same result.  Here is the code I am running...

```
File.open("test.txt", "r") {|file| puts file.read}
```

Here is the contents of the file...

> First line......1.
>
> Second line...2
>
> Third line.3

Here is what results...

> PS C:\Users\Alynn\rthw> ruby ex19.rb test.txt
>
> T h i r d   l i n e . 3 . . 2 . . . 1 .

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find any reason for it.

Comment: Does it have `\r` line endings instead of `\r\n` or `\n` line endings? Check it with a text editor (e.g. Nodepad++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working for me. You should check if you have \n on your txt files.

I copied your example and then run that on my irb

```
2.2.1 :006 > File.open("lines.txt", "r") {|file| puts file.read}
    First line......1.

    Second line...2

    Third line.3
 => nil
```

anyway this is code should be better for you

```
2.2.1 :007 > puts File.read("lines.txt")
    First line......1.

    Second line...2

    Third line.3
 => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text file uses Mac OS (CR / `'\r'`) instead of Unix (LF / `'\n'`) or Windows (CRLF / `'\r\n'`) newlines. On Windows (and most other operating systems) the **C**arriage **R**eturn character sets the device position to the beginning of the current line. That's why your output is overwritten by the next output.

It depends on your text editor how you can change the newline / line endings of a text file. However it can be also done with some Ruby code:

```
IO.write('test_fixed.txt', IO.read('test.txt', newline: :universal))
```

Passing [`newline: :universal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Encoding/Converter.html#method-c-new) to [`IO.read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-read) causes non-Unix newlines to be converted to Unix (or universal as Ruby calls them) newlines. [`IO.write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-write) then converts the Unix newline to native (Windows) newlines. If you don't want that pass `newline: :universal` to it too or simply use [`IO.binwrite`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-binwrite) instead.

It can be also used with your code if you don't want to edit your text file but still want to get the expected output:

```
File.open("test.txt", "r", newline: :universal) {|file| puts file.read}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, cremno had the right idea.  Somehow the text file I was reading from was encoded as "UCS-2 Big Endian", which Notepad++ refers to as "Mac" in the lower right corner.  When I converted the original text file to ANSI it fixed the problem, which is probably why Horacio Branciforte couldn't replicate the problem.

I figured it out by playing around with the encoding tags in the [IO.open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-open) method.  Thanks for the help!